# Understanding Solr charTermAttr methods

Tags: apache, search, solr, indexing, lucene

I can across a copy methods from charTermAttr from the org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute library.

Can anyone explain what copyBuffer and buffer does for charTermAttr? The documentation isn't very clear. If you could provide an example that would be great too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CharTermAttributeImpl` keeps internally a char array and a length variable that represents the internal term.

The `copyBuffer` method writes over this array by using the char array provided with the respective offset and length params.

The `buffer` method returns the internal array that you can directly modify. Additionally, you can get the term representation as a string by calling the attribute's toString method

Have a look at the javadocs for more details: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes/CharTermAttribute.html